# Grouping similar entrys

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a two tables, Post and categories, Post have category_id

I can get all post_name | category_id

with $post[Category][name], I can get

```
Post  |  Category       

Hello  |  php 
World  |  php    
Hi     |  php 
Earth  |  php
Hello1 |  asp 
World1 |  asp    
Hi1    |  asp 
Earth1 |  asp
```

How to get:

```
php

Hello  
World    
Hi     
Earth 

asp

Hello1 
World1   
Hi1    
Earth1
```

Its group by but Logic has gone and dont know how to get them

edit: I think there should be first loop that gets Categories than second inside first that gets posts where post.cat_id = cat.id But in cake way I dont know how can I do this.

Comment: Well how to do this on post controller!? In categories you can use contain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one query in your `Category` controller and a nested loop in the view:

in the `Category` controller:

```
function some_action () {
   $options = array (
      'recursive' => 1,
      'order' => array ( 'Category.name' => 'asc' )
   );
   $categories = $this->Category->find ( 'all', $options );
   $this->set ( 'categories', $categories );
}
```

and in the view:

```
<?php
foreach ( $categories as $c ) {
   echo $c['Category']['name'] . '<br />';
   foreach ( $c['Post'] as $p ) {
      echo ' &nbsp; ' . $p['name'] . '<br />';
   }
   echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: How about get same results from post controller?

Comment: do you have the `$hasMany` and `$belongsTo` in your models ?

Comment: if so, the action in the `Post` controller should be the same..  

just change the call: `$this->Category->find (...)` to `$this->Post->Category->find (...)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you can just tell me how to do same thing with one more table. Habtm thing. Add users that have more posts.

Comment: i'm sorry.. i didn't understand the last question!  you want to add another table `users`, a user hasMany posts belongsTo user ?

Comment: Its a habtm User <-> Post, So get posts from users and group them by category.

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving data using find() you can specify what to group by using the *group* param.
Here is the relevant chapter in the cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find

**EDIT** ignore above

So you should have

categories = array( 'Category' => array( 'name' => 'php', 'Posts' => array() ... );

In your view you then have:

```
<?php
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo $category['name'];
    foreach($category['Posts'] as $post) {
        echo $post['name'];
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Its giving me only one row of post. 

hello  | php
hello1 | asp

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, you can't use group by for this, it is for things like sum(). You will need to use multiple queries for this. First to find the distinct number of categories, then loop over the results querying for all the posts with that category set.

Comment: If you setup a category to have "hasMany" posts then when you query for a category the posts will come for free.

Comment: @Tnem : Yes, category hasMany posts belongsTo category. 

    `$ditricts = $this->Post->find('all',array('fields' => array('DISTINCT Category.name', 'Post.name'),'order'=>'Category.name'));`

Comment: this will give me an array of Posts and Categories, but same as without fields.

Comment: I think there should be first loop that gets Categories than second inside first that gets posts where post.cat_id = cat.id But in cake way I dont know how can I do this.

Comment: If:`$this->Category->find('all',array('contain' => 'Post'));` works how to reverse it.